# Can 2 different users from different country can connect to same Sauce labs account? is it possible using selecting same region?

Tags: timezone, cloud, saucelabs, http-tunneling

In my project there are different users from different country. Is it possible to use sauce labs to resolve this issue. I wanted to confirm, is it possible to select same region in sauce labs account from different countries in the world?
Can I make use of sauce tunnelling possible from different countries similar to VPN